# upload a file via RestEasy via MultipartOutput

Tags: java, resteasy

I'm trying to programmatically upload a file to an enpoint via RestEasyClient.

```
File file = new File("/Users/michele/path/file.txt");

MultipartOutput multipartOutput = new MultipartOutput();
multipartOutput.addPart(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE, "file.txt");
Entity<MultipartOutput> entity = Entity.entity(multipartOutput, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

//client is an instance of org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient
client
   .target("http://localhost:8080/endpoint")
   .request()
   .post(entity);
```

The problem is that the backend does not "find" the file that I uploaded

backend code

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(httpReq);
```

items is always empt.

Using MultipartFormDataOutput::addFormData, as described in many articles, works but does not fit my use case.

Also using apache.http.client.HttpClient works, but I prefer to avoid adding dependencies to my client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
The trick was to use MultipartFormDataOutput and to set the filename when adding a part

```
    MultipartFormDataOutput multipartOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    multipartOutput.addFormData("uploaded file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE, "file.txt");
```